# active record perform order on only last x records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have this active record collection and am using it in a sortable table within the view. I want the table to display the last 50 videos and I want to perform the ordering (of created_at, response_count, watched_count) on only these last 50 videos, but when I pass in the parameter to order them, it reselects from the entire collection of videos and then takes the last 50 after ordering.

Basically I'm wondering - how can I first take the 50 most recent videos and THEN order them by these attributes instead of doing the ordering first and then taking 50.

Even when I take the .order clause out and do that seperately, active record still treats @videos as a big sql query and combines everything together.

```
@videos = Video.select("videos.*,
                            COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.video_watched_count),0) AS watched_count,
                            COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.response_count),0) AS response_count,
                            COALESCE(SUM(video_activities.email_opened_count),0) AS email_opened_count,
                            MAX(video_activities.updated_at) AS last_activity")
                    .joins("INNER JOIN customers ON videos.customer_id = customers.id AND customers.id = #{current_customer.id}
                            LEFT JOIN video_activities ON videos.id = video_activities.video_id
                            LEFT JOIN people on videos.person_id = people.id")
                    .where.not(videos: {template: true})
                    .order("#{sort} #{params[:direction]}  NULLS LAST")
                    .group("#{group_by}")
                    .limit(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest is, fetch 50 most recent videos from the database using the query. Than order them by these attributes in memory. Don't do both the things in the same SQL query.

To do this, either covert `@videoes` to an array by using `to_a`, or directly use `sort` on it, as `order` will add another `order by` in the query and mess up your results.

Comment: I try, I move the .order out of the query and always do that separately but the entire thing still gets converted into 1 query.

@videos.order!("#{sort} #{params[:direction]}  NULLS LAST")

Comment: For that, instead of using ActiveRecord's method `order!` use ruby's `sort` function.

Comment: yeah I was thinking of converting it to an array then using sort but was having trouble with the correct parameters for the sort function

Comment: Yes, that is what you have to do, as `order` is an Active record function and it will append order by in the query, messing up your results.